# Probability flipping a coin

Tags: probability

[image]

Can you please explain. How to answer these type of questions with permutation/combination? Is there a way I should approach probability questions?

Comment: Hint: How many word of length $4$ are there, over the alphabet H, T, that have exactly two H. You can answer this with a "combination" or by listing the $16$ words over this alphabet, and counting the ones that have two H.

Comment: @graydad I think exactly twice and not in a row. They are mentioned usually seperately.

Comment: GMAT for such type of question you must first determine your probability space.

Comment: for clarification: it was asking for the probability that head shows up exactly twice. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to choose $2$ things out of $4$ is $\dbinom 4 2 = 6$.  Here are the six ways:
\begin{align}
HHtt \\[15pt]
HtHt \\[15pt]
HttH \\[15pt]
tHHt \\[15pt]
tHtH \\[15pt]
ttHH
\end{align}
All are equally probable.  So figure out what the probability of *one* of them is and continue from there.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not familiar with the (4 over 2) method. Could you explain? Do you just add 4 and 2 to get 6? 

- Never mind I got it. It's 4C2(4 throws want 2 heads) 4x3/2x1 over total possibilities 16.

Comment: No, it's $4$ (number of spots to put the first head) times $3$ (number of spots left to put the second head) divided by $2$ (because there isn't really an order to the two heads). That is, $4\cdot 3\,/\,2 = 6$. This is a called a [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) or _choose_ notation; read up at the link for more.

Comment: $\dbinom n k$ is the same as $_nC_k$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

How many ways are there to have two heads in four elements?  The answer is "4 choose 2".  What is the probability of getting each of these results?  Let's take a look at one possibility:  HHTT.  The probability of getting exactly this outcome is $\frac12 \frac12 \frac12 \frac12=\frac12^4$.  It becomes clear that the probability for all possibilities with two heads is $(1/2)^4$.  So the answer is $(4 \text{ choose } 2)\cdot\frac12^4.$

I'm not exactly sure why my answer was voted down.  Perhaps the person who did so would like to comment on why?

Comment: I don't know why your answer was voted down—perhaps a "fat-finger" vote. Anyway, I cancelled it with an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I propose two methods.

The first will follow what you have asked for.

### 1) By Combinations and Permutations (The multiplication principle)

First understand that by using combinations and permutations you are **counting**. Determining probabilities through counting means you have to eventually use the fundamental formula for probability. That is,

$$\mathcal{P}(E)=\frac{\mathrm{Number\ of\ Favourable\ Outcomes}}{\mathrm{Number\ of\ Total\ Outcomes}}.$$

These outcomes are all inside a **sample space**. We must therefore determine this sample space.

The denominator is easy to determine. So lets count. Given two letters "T" and "H", how many combinations of 4 can I make? Well by the multiplication principle, the answer is $2\times 2\times\ 2 \times 2 = 16$. We apply the same motive for the numerator. However, we require to choose 2 things of 4. That is the number of favourable outcomes is $\dbinom 4 2 = 6$ Thus our final probability is given by

$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{2\ Heads})=\frac{6}{16}.$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}.$$

### 2) By Mutually Inclusive/Exclusive Events

First realise that the final outcome generated (E.g. HHHH) is a multi-stage event. This is different from tossing a coin once. Since we are dealing with multi stage events we can use the following fact:

"If the outcomes are mutually inclusive, MULTIPLY their probabilities."
"If the outcomes are mutually exclusive, ADD their probabilities"

For this question, realise that the following outcome required arises through the following:

1) HHTT
2) HTHT
3) TTHH
4) THTH
5) HTTH
6) THHT

EACH final outcome above is mutually inclusive. Thus we multiply their individual multistage probabilities:

$$\mathcal{P}(HHTT) = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}.$$

In fact, the probabilities of the outcomes I listed above are all going to be the same! That is,

$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{HHTT})=\frac{1}{16}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{HTHT})=\frac{1}{16}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{TTHH})=\frac{1}{16}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{THTH})=\frac{1}{16}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{HTTH})=\frac{1}{16}$$
$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{THHT})=\frac{1}{16}$$

Now, all the **final** outcomes above, **collectively** are mutually exclusive. Therefore, we add the probabilities. Hence

$$\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{2\ Heads})= \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16} +\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{16}$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}.$$